# What is the biggest size of an object that iBox Nano can print?

Tags: ibox-nano

Since [iBox Nano](http://www.iboxprinters.com/) is the smallest public-production-available 3d Resin printer (and the cheapest so far), I assume it has a huge size limitation. So far I've only seen pictures of its outputs that are [miniature things](http://www.iboxprinters.com/ibox-nano-1/). I've never tried it nor have I seen it in action in person so I'd like to be sure.

**For example**, my 3D models are of the size of beads to figurines to a standard sized pencil cup holder.

**I want to know in inches or millimeters the dimension (width, length, height) of the biggest possible object the iBox Nano can print.**

Comment: It's not likely that you can consider the iBox Nano as a public production available printer, as the majority of Kickstarter backers have never received a printer nor a refund. Use care if you are going to be sending money to someone promising this model of printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On their [website](http://www.iboxprinters.com/ibox-nano-1/), I found the following picture, which states a build area of 40 mm x 20 mm x 90 mm (1.57" x 0,79" x 3.54").

[image: iBox Nano 3D printer specifications]

Answer (score -1):

From their website I found a [comparison between 300 microns down to 50 microns print quality](http://www.iboxprinters.com/pages.php?pageid=17). My answer would be somewhere around this range.

Comment: The question asks for maximum print size, not minimum feature size.